# memcache - searching key names containing multiple identifiers

Tags: php, python, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I'm new to memcache (via Amazon ElastiCache) and I'm using it to store data to offload some work from the database.

Currently I store 2 identical values where the key is a different lookup key.

For example:

```
// each key represents the user email address with the value a json dump of the user record
'email@email.com': {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'email@email.com'
}

// each key represents the user id with the value a json dump of the user record
1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'email@email.com'
}
```

Is it possible to store both the id/email in one key thus eliminating the need for 2 separate records stored in memory?

Any example in either Python or PHP would be most helpful!

Comment: This is just an idea, not tested, not researched, and it's only valid to even bother spending time on if the stored objects are of some size. What if you store the users on the most used lookup key, ie: (1: data). Then you store a reference on the email, like this: ('email@email.com':1).

When fetching by user id, then just do
$memcache->get(1);

When fetching after email you do
$id = $memcache->get('email@email.com');
$user = $memcache->get($id);

Comment: That is what I was considering doing next, have a simple key/value (email:id) lookup and then store the user info with id:data, it adds some latency and increases the ram storage slightly but I don't see another way around it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my data structure for doing that....don't judge, use at your own risk :P

```
class KeyedDictionaryReturn(object):
    def __init__(self, a, r):
        self.exact = a
        self.all = r
    def __str__(self):
        if self.exact: return str(self.exact)

class KeyedDictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(KeyedDictionary, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        _ret, _abs = [], None
        for keys, values in self.items():
            if isinstance(keys, tuple) and key in keys:
                _ret.append(dict.__getitem__(self, keys))
            elif isinstance(key, type(keys)) and key == keys:
                _abs = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
                _ret.append(_abs)
        if len(_ret) == 0:
            return None
        if len(_ret) == 1:
            return _ret[0]
        return KeyedDictionaryReturn(_abs, _ret)
```

simple usage:

```
>>> k = KeyedDictionary()
>>> k.update({(1, 'one'):1})
>>> print(k)
>>> print(k[1])
>>> print(k['one'])
{(1, 'one'): 1}
1
1
>>> k.update({2:2})
>>> k.update({(2, 'two'):3})
>>> print(k)
>>> print(k[2])
>>> print(k[2].exact)
>>> print(k[2].all)
{(1, 'one'): 1, 2: 2, (2, 'two'): 3}
2
2
[2, 3]
```

...I don't know if this is what you wanted or if this'll work in memcache without a hack.

Comment: That is a very interesting concept and definitely is useful for me in other apps, but from what I can tell of memcache it won't work unfortunately. Thanks though!